# How to save yourself from AWS charges?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I just started using Amazon web services, and I am using free tier version.

Due to some bitter experiences in past, I made budget to control price AWS charge me if I by mistake go beyond free tier limit.

[image]

I budgeted this to $1, so if the price goes beyond that, I get an email.
Is there any other filter/budget conditions I should implement so that AWS will not charge me anything? I am using AWS just for learning purpose.

Comment: I also get scared before using AWS!

Comment: There is no capability to 'stop' AWS from charging you anything. If you use a chargeable service outside of the Free Tier allowance, you will be charged for it. Using a notification is a good way to be aware of such a situation.

Comment: AWS has a training course as well as a lot of documentation on billing. Spend some time learning what things cost and how billing works and you will be more comfortable. https://www.aws.training/learningobject/video?id=15875

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to set a hard spending limit. This is discussed also [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216155/can-i-set-a-hard-limit-on-my-aws-spend) and in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021506/is-there-a-way-to-set-amazon-aws-billing-limit).

However AWS offers various other tools, such as budgets, for managing your costs. 
Extensive documentation about cost management can be found at the following resource:
https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/
There is also a page about specifically how to avoid charges with AWS Free Tier: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/free-tier-charges/

In general, I regularly get the feeling people overestimate the capabilities of the AWS free tier version. For any kind of production environment or meaningful computation you should expect actual charges to occur.

If it is just for learning purposes, make yourself familiar with what exactly the AWS Free Tier allows. Other than that, your budget is already a good way of monitoring your cost limit, also take a frequent look at your [AWS Billing Dashboard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home#/).

Comment: It seems this feature is under-discussion https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=58127